# Given $R^2$ and errorless values, how to compute standand error?

Tags: regression, r-squared

If I am working with a regression model of the form

$$ Y = X \beta + \epsilon,$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and $\epsilon \sim N_n(0, I_n \sigma^2)$ and I know that in the population, $R^2 = q$, how do I estimate $\sigma^2$ if all I have are $X \beta$ -- the error-less response variables?

Comment: Do you truly have $X\beta$ or do you have the *predicted* responses $X\hat \beta$?  Do you know $X$ itself or not?

Comment: I have the true $X\beta$ and $X$ alone is also know.